# How do I divide matrix elements by column sums in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matrix, column-sum

Is there an easy way to divide each matrix element by the column sum? For example:

```
input:

1  4

4  10

output:

1/5  4/14

4/5  10/14
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Here's a list of the different ways to do this ...

- ... using [`bsxfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html):

  ```
  B = bsxfun(@rdivide,A,sum(A));
  ```
- ... using [`repmat`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html):

  ```
  B = A./repmat(sum(A),size(A,1),1);
  ```
- ... using an [outer product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product) (as suggested by [Amro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/97160/amro)):

  ```
  B = A./(ones(size(A,1),1)*sum(A));
  ```
- ... and using a for loop (as suggested by [mtrw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/120261/mtrw)):

  ```
  B = A;
  columnSums = sum(B);
  for i = 1:numel(columnSums)
    B(:,i) = B(:,i)./columnSums(i);
  end
  ```

**Update:**

As of MATLAB R2016b and later, most built-in binary functions (list can be found [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html#inputarg_fun)) support implicit expansion, meaning they have the behavior of [`bsxfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) by default. So, in the newest MATLAB versions, all you have to do is:

```
B = A./sum(A);
```

Comment: Can't you throw the loop in just for completeness? :)

Comment: you can add this to the list: `B = A ./ (ones(size(A,1),1)*sum(A,1))`. I think its faster than *repmat* but slower than *bsxfun*

Comment: @Amro - nice, I hadn't thought of that one.

Comment: Thank you all very much for your help. I was curious which method is the fastest. Relative execution times are (applied to random matrix 3000x3000; experiment repeated 20 times; duration summed) fastest bsxfun (1.00), loop (1.09), ones (1.99), repmat (2.06). I am going to use the loop method :-).

Comment: bsxfun is better than a loop IMHO. Looks more functional.

Comment: Loop in MATLAB is a very bad idea. REPMAT and outer product look like the same thing. I did a tic toc analysis of these - RIPMAT is the fastest, followed by outer product followed by the anonymous function. Did not bother with the loop at all. (Tested on 2015a). size(A) = [25,1]

Comment: I just did a test and found bsxfun is the fastest.

Comment: Since R2016b, you can just do B = A./sum(A).

Answer (score 1):

```
a=[1 4;4 10]
a =
     1     4
     4    10

a*diag(1./sum(a,1))
ans =
    0.2000    0.2857
    0.8000    0.7143
```

Comment: +1, I like this one. Too bad it's 20 times slower than `bsxfun`.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't resist trying a list comprehension.  If this matrix was represented in a row-major list of lists, try this:

```
>>> A = [[1,4],[4,10]]
>>> [[float(i)/j for i,j in zip(a,map(sum,zip(*A)))] for a in A]
[[0.20000000000000001, 0.2857142857142857], [0.80000000000000004, 0.7142857142857143]]
```

Yes, I know that this is not super-efficient, as we compute the column sums once per row.  Saving this in a variable named colsums looks like:

```
>>> colsums = map(sum,zip(*A))
>>> [[float(i)/j for i,j in zip(a,colsums)] for a in A]
[[0.20000000000000001, 0.2857142857142857], [0.80000000000000004, 0.7142857142857143]]
```

Note that zip(*A) gives transpose(A).

Comment: Oh, sorry, yes it is.  I didn't notice the Matlab tag.