# How can I divide each row of a matrix by a fixed row?

Tags: matlab, loops, matrix

Suppose I have a matrix like:

```
100 200 300 400 500 600
  1   2   3   4   5   6
 10  20  30  40  50  60
...
```

I wish to divide each row by the second row (each element by the corresponding element), so I'll get:

```
100 100 100 100 100 100
  1   1   1   1   1   1
 10  10  10  10  10  10
...
```

Hw can I do it (without writing an explicit loop)?

Comment: Similar question: [How do I divide matrix elements by column sums in MATLAB?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1773099/97160)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use `bsxfun`:

```
outMat = bsxfun (@rdivide, inMat, inMat(2,:));
```

The 1st argument to `bsxfun` is a handle to the function you want to apply, in this case right-division.

Answer (score 27):

Here's a couple more equivalent ways:

```
M = [100 200 300 400 500 600
     1   2   3   4   5   6
     10  20  30  40  50  60];

%# BSXFUN
MM = bsxfun(@rdivide, M, M(2,:));

%# REPMAT
MM = M ./ repmat(M(2,:),size(M,1),1);

%# repetition by multiplication
MM = M ./ ( ones(size(M,1),1)*M(2,:) );

%# FOR-loop
MM = zeros(size(M));
for i=1:size(M,1)
    MM(i,:) = M(i,:) ./ M(2,:);
end
```

The best solution is the one using BSXFUN (as posted by [@Itamar Katz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4723824/how-can-i-divide-each-row-of-a-matrix-by-a-fixed-row/4723995#4723995))

Answer (score 6):

You can now use [array vs matrix operations](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/array-vs-matrix-operations.html).

This will do the trick :

```
mat = [100 200 300 400 500 600
     1   2   3   4   5   6
     10  20  30  40  50  60];

result = mat ./ mat(2,:)
```

which will output :

```
result =

   100   100   100   100   100   100
     1     1     1     1     1     1
    10    10    10    10    10    10
```

This will work in Octave and Matlab since R2016b.