# Subtracting two matrices with different dimensions

Tags: matlab, matrix, dimensions, subtraction

I have two matrices, one with 1x153 double and the other with 153x512 double and I require to subtract them while it is not possible and gives me error that they have not same dimensions.

Any idea how to solve it plz?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I divide each row of a matrix by a fixed row?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4723824/how-can-i-divide-each-row-of-a-matrix-by-a-fixed-row)

Answer (score 3):

Use [bsxfun](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html):

```
A = rand(1,153);
B = rand(153,152);

bsxfun(@minus,A.', B);
```

Notice that I first transposed `A` as one dimension needs to match at least.

Comment: Watch out, `A` might be complex. Better use `.'` instead of `'`.

Comment: @LuisMendo OP did specify `double`, but added the `.` anyways

Comment: Complex values can either be double or single precision (symbolic values can also be complex). Complexity is a distinct attribute from the class (`class(1i)` returns `'double'`). That's why `isfloat` and `isreal` exist.