# How to subtract a vector from each row of a matrix?

Tags: matlab, vector, matrix, subtraction

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I divide each row of a matrix by a fixed row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4723824/how-can-i-divide-each-row-of-a-matrix-by-a-fixed-row)

I'm  looking for an elegant way to subtract the same vector from each row of a matrix.  Here is a non elegant way of doing it.

```
a = [1 2 3];
b = rand(7,3);
c(:,1) = b(:,1) - a(1);
c(:,2) = b(:,2) - a(2);
c(:,3) = b(:,3) - a(3);
```

Also, the elegant way can't be slower than this method.

I've tried

```
c = b-repmat(a,size(b,1),1);
```

and it seems slower.

EDIT: The winner is this method.

```
c(:,1) = b(:,1) - a(1);
c(:,2) = b(:,2) - a(2);
c(:,3) = b(:,3) - a(3);
```

EDIT:  More methods, and tic toc results:

```
n = 1e6;
m = 3;
iter = 100;
a = rand(1,m);
b = rand(n,m);

tic
c = zeros(size(b));
for i = 1:iter
    c(:,1) = b(:,1) - a(1);
    c(:,2) = b(:,2) - a(2);
    c(:,3) = b(:,3) - a(3);
end
toc

tic
c = zeros(size(b));
for i = 1:iter
    c(:,1) = b(:,1) - a(1);
    c(:,2) = b(:,2) - a(2);
    c(:,3) = b(:,3) - a(3);
end
toc

tic
c = zeros(size(b));
for i = 1:iter
    for j = 1:3
        c(:,j) = b(:,j) - a(j);
    end
end
toc

tic
for i = 1:iter
    c = b-repmat(a,size(b,1),1);
end
toc

tic
for i = 1:iter
    c = bsxfun(@minus,b,a);
end
toc

tic
c = zeros(size(b));
for i = 1:iter
    for j = 1:size(b,1)
        c(j,:) = b(j,:) - a;
    end
end
toc
```

results

```
Elapsed time is 0.622730 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.627321 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.713384 seconds.
Elapsed time is 2.621642 seconds.
Elapsed time is 1.323490 seconds.
Elapsed time is 17.269901 seconds.
```

Comment: This is basically a duplicate of these other questions (same idea, different arithmetic operation): [How do I divide matrix elements by column sums in MATLAB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1773099/how-do-i-divide-matrix-elements-by-column-sums-in-matlab), [How can I divide each row of a matrix by a fixed row?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4723824/how-can-i-divide-each-row-of-a-matrix-by-a-fixed-row)

Comment: For those too lazy to follow the links: `c=bsxfun(@minus,b,a);`

Comment: bsxfun seems slower, see edit

Comment: For your timings: take those c and b initializations out of the loop, and please try to vary the size (7, 3) with more interesting values, like something in the range 1e2... 1e4. And if you really have a real use case, care to describe it! Thanks

Comment: I found that since 2016, the following method would work (matrix-array operation). 
`c = b .- a`
Not sure regarding the timing, but this should be reasonably fast and straightforward.

Comment: @OlgaGnatenko Can you share a link for this functionality? This doesn't appear to be supported in Matlab 2019b.

Answer (score 6):

Here is my contribution:

`c = b - ones(size(b))*diag(a)`

Now speed testing it:

```
tic
for i = 1:10000
    c = zeros(size(b));
    b = rand(7,3);
    c = b - ones(size(b))*diag(a);
end
toc
```

The result:

`Elapsed time is 0.099979 seconds.`

Not quite as fast, but it is clean.

Comment: This also works: `b - ones(size(b, 1), size(a, 1)) * a`

Comment: Note that if size(b) is very large, this will be very slow and extremely inefficient in memory. repmat will likely work better in that case.

Answer (score 1):

There are only three obvious answers, and you gave two of them in your question.

The third is by row,

```
c(1,:) = b(1,:) - a; %...
```

but I'd expect that to be slower than your by-column processing for large matrixes since it accesses elements out of memory order.

If you turn your by-column processing into a `for` loop in a *.m file or subfunction, is it still faster than the `repmat` version?

One other thing you might test for speed: Try preallocating `c`.

```
c = zeros(size(b));
c(:,1) = b(:,1) - a(1); %...
```

Comment: The fourth is by using `bsxfun`, as explained in the duplicate answers as well as my comment.