# Subtract 1 x M matrix from N x M matrix in ejml

Tags: java, matrix, subtraction, ejml

Assuming a 1 x M (A) and N x M (B) SimpleMatrix objects in ejml, is there a simple way to subtract A from B?  I was looking for a way to repeat the rows of A to be the size of B, but didn't find the method to do this easily.

```
SimpleMatrix A = new SimpleMatrix(1, 2);
SimpleMatrix B = new SimpleMatrix(2, 2);

A.set(1.0);

B.setRow(0, 0, 2.0, 2.0);
B.setRow(1, 0, 4.0, 4.0);

// Throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
// The 'a' and 'b' matrices do not have compatible dimensions
SimpleMatrix C = B.minus(A);

// Expecting
// 1 1
// 3 3
```

Many answers using matlab ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4723824/how-can-i-divide-each-row-of-a-matrix-by-a-fixed-row) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5342857/how-to-subtract-a-vector-from-each-row-of-a-matrix)), but I couldn't find a simple syntax for ejml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [docs](http://ejml.org/javadoc/org/ejml/equation/Equation.html):

> Will concat A and B along their columns and then concat the result with  C along their rows.
>                   [A,B;C]

So you could define an equation which will construct a matrix from repeated rows with like (I don't know the `N` value of `B` matrix):

```
A.equation("A = [A,A,A]")
```

or

```
A.equation("A = [A,A,A]", "A")
```

The other option is to use [`SimpleBase.concatColumns(SimpleBase...)`](http://ejml.org/javadoc/org/ejml/simple/SimpleBase.html#concatColumns-org.ejml.simple.SimpleBase...-), it looks like this:

```
A = A.concatColumns(A,A)
```

Assuming A is `1xM` it will produce `3xM` matrix and store it in `A`. If you desire to construct such array dynamically you could just concatenate "A," N times (without trailing coma of course) or pass `N - 1` times matrix `A` to function.

**UPDATE**

Sorry, its late I wrongly assumed A is row vector, as it is column vector use comas instead of semicolons, as described in docs.

Comment: Thanks much.  I assume you mean "comma" instead of "colon" in your answer (for row concatenation).  I'm surprised you have to use an equation to accomplish this - I would have thought there was some kind of a repeat method.

Comment: oooh, you've had the gut! there are methods `concatRows` and `concatColumns` but defined for `SimpleBase` (superclass for `SimpleMatrix`) so I didn't notice them at first glance... I'll update my answer accordingly