# How do I divide matrix elements by *non-zero* column sums in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matrix, column-sum

I see this question: [How do I divide matrix elements by column sums in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1773099/how-do-i-divide-matrix-elements-by-column-sums-in-matlab)

But additionally, I want to do the division only if the column sum (`sum(A)`) is non-zero.
Will any of the listed methods there work, except for the loop-method as it is very slow for my matrix size?

Answer (score 1):

All you need is do remove the zero elements from `sum(A)` with an intermediate step:

```
col_sum = sum(A);
col_sum( col_sum == 0 ) = 1; % no zeros
```

Now you can use any method in [the linked post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1773099/how-do-i-divide-matrix-elements-by-column-sums-in-matlab), e.g. using `bsxfun`:

```
B = bsxfun(@rdivide, A, col_sum);
```

---

From numerical point of view, eliminating only elements that are **exactly** zero when `A` is a floating point type, is not a very good practice. Instead you might want to eliminate all *close to zero* elements:

```
col_sum( abs(col_sum) < 1e-10 ) = 1;
```