# Need help vectorizing a loop in Matlab

Tags: matlab, vectorization

My brain is hardwired with C++ mindset. Need help vectorizing the following loop.

This code is trying to generate a C++ header that contains an array that maps every pixel location of an distorted image to the undistorted coordinates.

FYI `cameraParams` and `imgIntrinsics` are already previously generated by the `estimateFisheyeParameters` function and `undistortFisheyeImage` image previously.

```
fileID = fopen('undistorted.h', 'w');

fprintf(fileID, '#ifndef UNDISTORTED_H\n#define UNDISTORTED_H\n\n');
fprintf(fileID, 'const float distortionFix[%d][%d][2] = {', mrows, ncols);
for y = 1:mrows
    fprintf(fileID, '{');
    for x = 1:ncols
        undistortedPoint = undistortFisheyePoints([x y], cameraParams.Intrinsics);
        undistortedPoint = undistortedPoint - imgIntrinsics.PrincipalPoint;
        fprintf(fileID, '{%f, %f}', undistortedPoint);
        if x < ncols
            fprintf(fileID, ', ');
        end
    end
    if (y < mrows)
        fprintf(fileID, '},\n');
    end
end
fprintf(fileID, '}};\n\n#endif');
```

Comment: Why do you need vectorization here? Does this code take much longer to execute than compiling the resulting header file?

Comment: @CrisLuengo It's just a good excercise to get into the matlab mindset, plus I just hate waiting. The task itself is indeed not time-sensitive

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best place to start would be to recognize that [`undistortFisheyePoints`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/undistortfisheyepoints.html) can accept a matrix of coordinate points, so calling it once with a matrix input will likely be more efficient than calling it repeatedly in a loop. You would just have to create the point matrix (which can be done using [`repmat`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html) and [`repelem`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repelem.html)), get your matrix of undistorted points, then subtract `imgIntrinsics.PrincipalPoint` from each row (either by using [implicit expansion](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2016/10/24/matlab-arithmetic-expands-in-r2016b/), [`bsxfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html), or [explicitly replicating it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1773099/52738)). This can all be done outside the loop, and then you only need one loop to print it all out:

```
fileID = fopen('undistorted.h', 'w');

fprintf(fileID, '#ifndef UNDISTORTED_H\n#define UNDISTORTED_H\n\n');
fprintf(fileID, 'const float distortionFix[%d][%d][2] = {', mrows, ncols);

points = [repmat((1:ncols).', mrows, 1) repelem((1:mrows).', ncols, 1)];
undistortedPoints = undistortFisheyePoints(points, cameraParams.Intrinsics);
undistortedPoints = bsxfun(@minus, undistortedPoints, imgIntrinsics.PrincipalPoint);

for y = 1:mrows
    fprintf(fileID, '{');
    index = ((y-1)*ncols+1):(y*ncols-1);
    fprintf(fileID, '{%f, %f},', undistortedPoints(index, :).');
    fprintf(fileID, '{%f, %f}', undistortedPoints(y*ncols, :));
    if (y < mrows)
        fprintf(fileID, '},\n');
    end
end
fprintf(fileID, '}};\n\n#endif');
```